# How to compare an escaped field in PHP/MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm not really sure why I'm having this issue but at the moment I'm blocked. The problem that I'm having is that when using Doctrine to insert into MySQL, some values are automatically escaped. For example, on a form where a user inputs something such as `he/she`, the data stored into the MySQL table is `he\/she`.

Now, the issue is that sometimes the user will use a search function, but using `he/she` won't give them any results. How can I solve this? I'm thinking on escaping the characters on the string that I pass to the LIKE function, is this a correct approach? I'm thinking that the same issue will happen if the user has values such as `this is 50%` (the percent would need to be converted as well before given to the `LIKE` function?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to solve this at the core - the data should never enter into your database. A probable cause of this is a misconfigured web server that still has [magic quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) enabled with MSSQL mode, or using a library that tries to do input sanitation in a (very) wrong way. You should ***never ever ever*** want to fix this on the search end of things - once you start patching there for corrupted data you're in for an endless cesspool of problems.

Debug why the data is going in wrong, and fix it there.

Comment: Thanks... I discovered that this has to do with the fact that the data is being stored as JSON inside those fields, and JSON escapes '/' with '\/'. Any tips on how to search JSON fields? I tried json_encode($data) but I get nothing back. Even directly typing the query in MySQL 'SELECT .... WHERE C like '%he\/she%' gives me no results, although removing the 'he' gives me the results (LIKE '%\/she%' works)